# variable truth table to CNF / DNF

Tags: python, python-3.x, boolean-logic, boolean-expression, boolean-operations

My code purpose is to create this truth table that is in the attached picture, however it is not working the code. The output for this code get different results from the truth table

**The truth table:**

[image: The truth table image press here].

It needs to be identical to the truth table in the picture. I hope someone can figure out my mistake!

```
def cnf(a, b, c, d):
    return [
        [a, b, c, d], #2
        [not a, not b, not c, d],  #3
        [not a, not b, c, not d], #4
        [ not a, not b, c, d], #5555 
        [a, not b, c, d],    #6
        [a, not b, c, not d], #777 [ 
        [a, not b, not c, d],  #8    
        [a, not b,  c, d], #1 [a, not b, not c, not d],
    ]

def dnf(a, b, c, d):
    return [
        [not a, b, c, d], #1
        [ a, not b, not c, d], 
        [a, not b , not c, not d],  #7777 [a, not b ,  c, not d],
        [ not a, b , not c, not d], #6
        [a, b, not c, not d],  #5
        [ a, b , not c, d], #4
        [a,  b , c, not d], #3
        [not a, not b , not c, not d], #2
    ]
```

Answer (score 1):

So, the [Karnaugh map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map) corresponding to that truth table is:

```
      C'D'  C'D   CD    CD'
A'B'  1     0     0     0
A'B   1     0     1     0
AB    0     0     1     0
AB'   1     1     1     1
```

Where the apostrophe `'` means negation.

You can group last row and the pairs of ones in first and third column. The logical expression corresponding to your truth table therefore is

[image]

[image: 2]]

Now that you know the logical expression of your truth table, it should be easy to print it out with the help of a simple function like this:

```
def is_it_true(a, b, c, d):
    return (a and not b or not a and not c and not d or b and c and d)
```

Comment: however I need stay in my format of code that I did though

Answer (score 1):

The `DNF` `minterms` directly relate to the `T` rows of the truth table
while the `CNF` `maxterms` (`clauses`) correspond to the `F` rows.

```
               DNF                    CNF
    A B C D f  A B C D                A B C D
15  T T T T T  T T T T   a  b  c  d
14  T T T F F                         F F F T  !a !b !c  d
13  T T F T F                         F F T F  !a !b  c !d
12  T T F F F                         F F T T  !a !b  c  d
11  T F T T T  T F T T   a !b  c  d 
10  T F T F T  T F T F   a !b  c !d
09  T F F T T  T F F T   a !b !c  d
08  T F F F T  T F F F   a !b !c !d
07  F T T T T  F T T T  !a  b  c  d 
06  F T T F F                         T F F T   a !b !c  d
05  F T F T F                         T F T F   a !b  c !d
04  F T F F T  F T F F  !a  b !c !d
03  F F T T F                         T T F F   a  b !c !d
02  F F T F F                         T T F T   a  b !c  d
01  F F F T F                         T T T F   a  b  c !d
00  F F F F T  F F F F  !a !b !c !d
```

For `DNF`, the `T` rows are translated to `minterms`.
Every input `T` yields a non-inverted input, while `F` yields an inverted input.
A `DNF` minterm is a logical `AND` of inputs.

For `CNF`, the `F` rows correspond to `clauses` or `maxterms`.
Every input `T` yields an inverted input, while `F` results in a non-inverted input.
A `CNF` `maxterm`/`clause` is a logical `OR` of inputs. Every input has to be inverted
wrt. to the truth table row to prevent the `F` output.